# Cant' use `valgrind function profiler` due to "No private key file given." error

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, valgrind

I'm trying to use *valgrind function profiler* inside Ubuntu SDK but when I start the app I receive this error:

```
Error: "/usr/bin/valgrind" could not be started: No private key file given.
```

What can I do?

Comment: How you installed the SDK?

Comment: @Braiam I'm on Ubuntu 13.10, I've added _ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa_ and then installed _ubuntu-sdk_